# Inbound and outbound call

Tags: voip

After googling I come to know some basic definition as,
Outbound calls - A call center agent or representative contacts the customer.
Inbound calls - A call center agent or representative takes calls coming into the contact center.

My questions are, 
1 Are these terms applicable to call centre setup only ?
2 Routing of inbound call is diffrent from routing of outbound call(Technical aspects like protocol, switching methods etc)?
3 Whether calls are handled diffrently based on inbound & outbound, by network elements?

Answer (score 0):

These are not specific to callcenters only.
-Outbound calls means all calls from your internal network routed outside (to the public internet or to another carriers). Usually more complex routing rules are applied for this (for example you might route prefix A to carrier X and prefix B to carrier Y)
-Inbound calls are the opposite. Usually there are no any routing rules (except authentication) and you just try to match the incoming call with one of your extension. If the target is not present in your network then you might reject the call or forward to the appropriate network